# Oracle to SQL server Migration Date Format changes

Tags: sql-server, oracle, to-char

I Used `SELECT TO_CHAR(sysDate,'dy') FROM DUAL` In oracle and I want to get the same output in SQL Server. I tried several ways and I want to know the date style value for this format.

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(max),'2017-03-06T00:00:00.000',<DateStyle>)
```

Comment: You can't get the day with the CONVERT format. Try this instead: **SELECT LEFT(DATENAME(weekday, '2017-03-06T00:00:00.000'), 3)**

Comment: @t-clausen.dk thank you for the comment, and I could manage my requirement on your comment